# How to create a UIColor from a String like "rgb(0,0,0)"?

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, uicolor

I have a string from server in a format like "rgb(0,0,0)", which should be used on some UI elements.

The main problem is the various colours like "rgb(20,120,4)" etc.

Is there a way to parse it in something like `UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)`?

Comment: in what format is the server returned code? String? please post some more code so I can help you

Comment: I would just strip of the first characters, however that isn't very good to do, shall I show you how to do that?

Comment: "Is there a way to parse it" Yes, there is (though I don't quite see how you would derive alpha info, since you have no alpha info to start with).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are so many possible solutions! Here is one using
[`NSScanner`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/):

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(rgbString : String) {
        var red = 0.0
        var green = 0.0
        var blue = 0.0
        
        let scanner = NSScanner(string : rgbString)
        guard scanner.scanString("rgb(", intoString: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&red)
            && scanner.scanString(",", intoString: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&green)
            && scanner.scanString(",", intoString: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&blue)
            && scanner.scanString(")", intoString: nil) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red/255.0), green: CGFloat(green/255.0), blue: CGFloat(blue/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
if let col = UIColor(rgbString: "rgb(20,120.5, 4)") {
    print(col)
} else {
    print("invalid color specification")
}
```

**Update for Swift 3/4:**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(rgbString: String) {
        var red = 0.0
        var green = 0.0
        var blue = 0.0
        
        let scanner = Scanner(string: rgbString)
        guard scanner.scanString("rgb(", into: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&red)
            && scanner.scanString(",", into: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&green)
            && scanner.scanString(",", into: nil)
            && scanner.scanDouble(&blue)
            && scanner.scanString(")", into: nil) else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red/255.0), green: CGFloat(green/255.0), blue: CGFloat(blue/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

**Update for Swift 5:**

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init?(rgbString: String) {

        let scanner = Scanner(string: rgbString)
        guard scanner.scanString("rgb(") != nil,
              let red = scanner.scanDouble(),
              scanner.scanString(",") != nil,
              let green = scanner.scanDouble(),
              scanner.scanString(",") != nil,
              let blue = scanner.scanDouble(),
              scanner.scanString(")") != nil else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(red: CGFloat(red/255.0), green: CGFloat(green/255.0), blue: CGFloat(blue/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method which will convert your string to the `UIColor`. Possibly there is even better solution with regex, but I'm pretty bad in regex.

```
func colorFromString(colorString: String) -> UIColor? {
    // strip down rgb and parenthesis
    let combinedCharacterSet = NSMutableCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
    combinedCharacterSet.addCharactersInString("()")

    let trimmedString = colorString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(combinedCharacterSet)
    let rgbValueStrings = trimmedString.componentsSeparatedByString(",")

    if rgbValueStrings.count != 3 {
        return nil
    }

    if let r =  Double(rgbValueStrings[0]) where r >= 0 && r <= 255,
        let g =  Double(rgbValueStrings[1]) where g >= 0 && g <= 255,
        let b =  Double(rgbValueStrings[2]) where b >= 0 && b <= 255 {
        return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r/255), green: CGFloat(g/255), blue: CGFloat(b/255), alpha: 1.0)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

and playground can be [downloaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/phz6socvrivafrx/AAAt9kLNKGQQr0lYjFtUMNrIa?dl=0)

Comment: You may also want to trim space characters after splitting to individual strings, as whitespace around the number will not be parsed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
import UIKit

let string1 = "rgb(25.00,100.0,100)"

let indexToRemoveTheLast = string1.endIndex.advancedBy(-1)
let substring1 = string1.substringToIndex(indexToRemoveTheLast)
let indexToRemoveTheFirst = string1.startIndex.advancedBy(4)
let substring2 = substring1.substringFromIndex(indexToRemoveTheFirst)

var colorsString = substring2.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)
let red = (Float(colorsString[0])!) / 255
let green = (Float(colorsString[1])!) / 255
let blue = (Float(colorsString[2])!) / 255

let myColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: 1)
```

the result here:

[image]

Comment: Nice solutions to use the extensions!

Comment: that code won't work. `Int` is a wrong type for color constructor, it will fail with color code more than 1 digit or if you receive some badly formatted string

Comment: You didn't fix the second issue I pointed out (the rgb values need to be divided by 255 to be between 0 and 1 for the `UIColor` initializer)

Comment: Try your code with "rgb(10,0,10)" and "rgb(255,0,255)".  They will both result in the same color because `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha:)` expects values between 0-1 and anything greater than 1 is treated as if you passed in 1.

Comment: There various issues with your code: you do worse unwrap. You shouldn't. You don't check numbers range, you don't check if it's number at all. Finally,  as @dan pointed out, you don't divide result to 255.